# ASP.NET MVC3: ValidationMessageFor on new line

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a validation message for my model:

```
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="rereg-input">
           @Html.TranslatedTextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
         </div>
     </td>
```

When the user forgets, the text nicely displays a * beside the field:

[image]

But when they enter a bad email, the message gets put on the end. How can I get it under?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to rearrange/fix the CSS/HTML structure.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <div class="rereg-input">
        @Html.TranslatedTextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        <div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

You may be better off modifying whatever CSS class MVC puts on the validation message element and set `display:block;`.

```
.validation-message {
    /* ... */
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Like the Div only trick, it works great in FireFox and Chrome, but not IE9.

Comment: That is very strange if a plain `div` does not put it on a new line. Perhaps the CSS for `.rereg-input div` has a `float` rule? Try `<div style="float:none;display:block;">` to check this.

Comment: You can inspect the element and see the styles on it by right-clicking on it in most browsers.

Comment: BINGO, the float was the issue in IE

Comment: Awesome :) find that CSS and get rid of the float and it should work.

Comment: You don't really need to rearrange the HTML structure. `Html.ValidationMessageFor` already generates a span element with class `field-validation-error` for you. So you can just target that on your CSS selector and leave your HTML intact.

Answer (score 6):

Simply surrounding it with a div should do the trick

```
<div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)</div>
```